# Using Jquery to generate buttons with unique hrefs

Tags: javascript, jquery

OK so this may be a little complex so bear with me.

I have a block of HTML with several hidden fields in it that have coordinates:

```
    <div id="content">
<div class="event">
    Blah blah blah
    <input id="e1coords" class="coords" name="e1coords" type="hidden" value="-27.482359,153.024725" />
</div>

<div class="event">
    blah blah blah
    <input id="e2coords" class="coords" name="e2coords" type="hidden" value="-27.471134,153.0182" />
</div>
<div class="event">
    blah blah blah
    <input id="e3coords" class="coords" name="e3coords" type="hidden" value="-27.471667,153.023704" />
</div>
    </div>
```

I have some code thats supposed to take the value from each hidden input (coordinates) and transfer it into part of the href url. EG:

```
   //GET COORDS
            $(content).find('.coords').each(function() {
                var coords = $(this).val();

                //CREATE BUTTON, ADD VALUE FROM
                var input2 = '<div class="inputholder"><a class="viewmap" href="maptest.html?longlat='+ coords +' "><button>Find on Map</button></a></div>';
                //ATTACH BUTTON
                $(input2).insertAfter($('#showday1 .save_event'));
            });
```

This works OK to a point. It creates a button for each input (so in the example above 3 buttons are created) but dislpays them 3 times each. So from the HTML above I get 9 buttons where there should be 3.

Can any one suggest a way to display the button just once per hidden input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your generated buttons to be placed right after each hidden input HTML field (based on your input) I'd go like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
           $(content).find('.coords').each(function() { 
                var coords = $(this).val(); 
                var input2 = '<div class="inputholder"><a class="viewmap" href="maptest.html?longlat='+ coords +' "><button>Find on Map</button></a></div>'; 
                $(this).after(input2);
            });   
});
```

As you have already detected the inputs (with class `coords`) the `after` jQuery function should append the desired content right after each of the hidden inputs

---

On the other hand if you just want all the buttons to be placed on the end of the `div` with `id=content`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
           var input2="";
           $(content).find('.coords').each(function() { 
                var coords = $(this).val(); 
                input2 += '<div class="inputholder"><a class="viewmap" href="maptest.html?longlat='+ coords +' "><button>Find on Map</button></a></div>'; 
            }); 
            $(content).after(input2);
});
```

In this approach we aggregated all of the generated inputs (for each hidden input) and in the end we appended them to the wrapper `div`

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED:**

Your Code is working also fine. [**SEE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/UVnhm/1/)

Do you have the following HTML block in your page?

```
<div id="showday1">
    <div class="save_event">save event</div>
</div>
```

**Note:** The above code refers this line `$('#showday1 .save_event')`

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
$('#content .coords').each(function() {
     var coords = $(this).val();
     //CREATE BUTTON, ADD VALUE FROM
     var input2 = '<div class="inputholder"><a class="viewmap" href="maptest.html?longlat='+ coords +' "><button>Find on Map</button></a></div>';
     //ATTACH BUTTON
      $(input2).appendTo($(this).parent()); //This append the button on the div event, change with #showday1 ...
});
```